# Is there a positive integer $n$ such that $\lfloor 10^n\pi\rfloor$ is palindromic?

Tags: irrational-numbers, pi

$\pi$ is irrational, and of course its digits are not a repeating sequence. However I cannot wrap my head around the following...

> Is there a digit $x$ in $\pi$ such that the digits before are repeated in reverse order after that digit?
> $$\pi = 3.14159\ldots zyxxyz \ldots 951413 [\ldots]$$
>
> In other words, is there a positive integer $n$ such that $\lfloor 10^n\pi\rfloor$ is [palindromic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindromic_number)?

$\pi$ has infinite digits, but it is unknown whether any sequence of digits will appear at some point. Moreover, this isn't just a requirement for $n$ digits appearing at some position, but for a sequence of $n$ digits has to appear at position $n$.

Comment: "Pi has infinite digits, so any sequence of digits will appear at some point."  Why is that?

Comment: Regarding what @Randall said (I was about to comment myself, then saw his/her comment), note that the digit $2$ does not appear in the following irrational number: $0.101001000100001000001\ldots$ (pattern of $1$'s and $0$'s continues in the suggested pattern)

Comment: @an4s well my question was based on a false premise, and as the answer to the other question is "not really" it also does answer this one...

Comment: You can restate your question as: *"Is there a positive integer $n$ such that $\lfloor 10^n\pi\rfloor$ is [palindromic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindromic_number)?"* ... The answer to this is presumably independent of whether "any sequence of digits" appears in $\pi$, so this is a perfectly reasonable stand-alone question. (So, I don't believe this question should have been closed as a duplicate.) In any case, I'd be pretty surprised if the answer were "Yes".

Comment: For those interested, I collected together a lot of Mathematics Stack Exchange questions  (made before 9 April 2018) relating to digits of $\pi$ (among other related topics) in my answer to [Normal Numbers as members of a larger set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2729156/13130)

Comment: @Blue you are right, I edited accordingly. Anyhow, I'm still be fine with the duplicate, that wrong assumption aside I don't believe anymore that such digit exists

Comment: A heuristic argument, assuming $\pi$ has "random" digits: since $\sum_{n\ge1}10^{-n/2}=\frac{1}{10-\sqrt{10}}\ll1$, (i) there probably is no such $n$ & (ii) there almost certainly are no more than a few such $n$.