# Does a disjunctive sequence contain every finite sequence infinitely many times?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The definition of a disjunctive sequence is an infinite sequence (in some base $b$), which contains all finite base $b$ words at least once. However, does that automatically imply it contains all finite base $b$ words infinitely many times?

Comment: The following special case is sufficient for the general case. Consider the digit string $33871.$ Since the sequence is disjunctive, the digit string $3387133871$ appears somewhere, and the digit string $338713387133871$ appears somewhere, and the digit string $33871338713387133871$ appears somewhere, etc. So not only does $33871$ appear infinitely often, every finitely-iterated concatenation of $33871$ appears (hence, every finitely-iterated concatenation of $33871$ appears infinitely often). FYI, [this collection of links](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2729156/13130) may be of interest.