# Does pi's decimal expansion certainly repeat once (of course not infinitely many times)??

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, pi

My 8-year-old asked me this and I could see arguments for either answer.

Is pi guaranteed to have an expansion of the form

```
3.NNM
```

where N is a finite sequence of digits?  For example, 3.14151415696745... (N=1415) or 3.1415926141592696033... (N=1415926).  Of course these are not the true value of N.

**Argument for:**

At any position P in the expansion, The chance of the next P digits being equal to the first P is nonzero. Since there are an infinite number of positions P, eventually we will succeed.

**Argument against:**

The chance of succeeding at P=1 is 1 in 10.  (We fail, as pi does not begin with 3.11). The chance of succeeding at P=2 is 1 in 100. (Fail again: pi does not begin with 3.1414).  Etc.  If I play a game where I attempt to succeed at P=1, and then at P=2, and repeat infinitely until I succeed, the fact that the chance at each step becomes 10 times less causes the total probability to converge on a number less than 100%.

Which argument is correct, if either? If it's the latter, what is the overall probability that we converge upon?

Comment: It is highly certain, but not proved, that pi is a normal number, which means that all finite strings of digits reoccur infinitely often at equal rates.

Comment: but you seem to be reasoning about a stream of random digits, whereas pi is not random at all, and each digit is 100% known with certainty. The probability of the digit coming after 3.14 being 1 is 100%, and 0% for every other digit.

Comment: *(repeating a comment I made 5 days ago to [this similar MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4736517/13130))* Many relevant previous questions are given in my answer to [Normal Numbers as members of a larger set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2728446/13130)

Comment: The argument against is closer to being right; it says that there’s a fixed probability $p \in (0,1)$ that an infinite string of random digits starts with a repeated string.  The probability is roughly $1/10+1/100+1/1000+…=1/9$ (but not exactly, as this overcounts somewhat).  But the digits of $\pi$ are not random, and moreover we know trillions of them, so I think the probability of this is essentially zero.

Comment: @mjqxxxx's argument is correct: the likelihood that $\pi$ has the property you want is vanishingly tiny.  I will write this up in the morning if nobody else does it first.

Comment: To add to what @mjqxxxx has said: assuming that you can treat digits of $\pi$ as a random sequence, and assuming that we _know_ `3.NNM` situation doesn't happen in the first $k$ digits, where $k$ is in the "trillions", then the chances it will happen _later_ are (about) $10^{-k-1}+10^{-k-2}+10^{-k-3}+\ldots=\frac{1}{9}10^{-k}$, which is an incredibly small number $\approx 0.000\cdots 0111$ with $k$ zeros after the decimal point!

Comment: That is the calculation I gave in my Answer , @mjqxxxx , though I think it is not $10^{-1}$ , it is $100^{-1}$ , giving $1/99$ , not $1/9$. Either way , OP Pattern is unlikely , taking "specific" transcendental number $t$ & maybe likely when taking "random" transcendental number out of all transcendental numbers !!

Comment: @ziggurism It is not even "highly certain" that $\pi$ is normal. We are extremely far away from proving this. We do not even know whether some specific digit , say $7$ , occurs infinite many often. In fact, we cannot rule out that $\pi$ eventually consists only of the digits $0$ and $1$. The only evidence is that upto a very high limit , the digits behave like randomly generated.

Comment: But it is correct that the chance that $\pi$ has this property is almost $0$. The chance of a repitition decreases exponential , so we cannot argue that we must have eventually a hit (even if we assume random digits which is , as pointed out , not the case !). We won't be able to prove it , but we can (considering how long the string would have to be , it takes quite a while until "1415" occurs again) safely assume that $\pi$ does NOT have the desired property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this question deserves some sort of conclusion. Pretty much everything that makes sense has been covered in the comments, this is just a bit more sorted write-up.

First of all, assume that digits of $\pi$ can be treated as random digits. Which is unproven and there could still be a hidden regularity in the sequence of the digits.

The OP's first argument doesn't really work. The sum of infinitely many numbers (in this case small probabilities) does not need to be infinite. It doesn't even need to be $1$. Whatever misconception is behind this argument, it is certainly reminiscent of [Zeno's paradoxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes#Achilles_and_the_tortoise), which makes us think that Achilles would never catch up with the tortoise.

As for the *second* argument, let's say we already know $k$ digits of $\pi$ after the decimal point (or a few more), and we *know* that $\pi$ is not representable in the form `3.NNM` where $N$ is up to $k$ digits long. For example, apparently [we know $10^{14}$ digits of $\pi$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology_of_computation_of_%CF%80) and I will assume that repetition is not observed anywhere in those digits. (Or at least in $k=10^{14}-1$ digits: as per the above article, the $10^{14}$th digit is $0$ so repetition is not happening at that point either.)

The probability that $\pi$ will be of the form `3.NNM` is bounded *from above* by the following sum:

- The probability that the subsequent $k+1$ digits will match the first $k+1$ digits,
- The probability that the subsequent $k+2$ digits will match the first $k+2$ digits,
- The probability that the subsequent $k+3$ digits will match the first $k+3$ digits,
- etc.

I am not saying the probability is *equal* to the sum above because the above events are not mutually exclusive, but it is certainly *less than or equal* to the sum above.

Now, the probabilities above are, respectively: $10^{-(k+1)}, 10^{-(k+2)}, 10^{-(k+3)}, \ldots$ - and the sum of those is:

$$\sum_{i=k+1}^\infty 10^{-i}=10^{-k-1}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{10}}=\frac{1}{9}10^{-k}$$

(summation of a geometric series). This is an incredibly small number if $k$ is large (in the trillions): it is really:

$$0.\underbrace{000\cdots0}_{k\text{ zeros}}111\cdots$$

and the chance that the repetition happens is, as I said, even smaller than that.

So, the conclusion would be: assuming that digits of $\pi$ can be treated as random digits, and knowing that the repetition does not happen within the first $k$ digits, where $k\approx 10^{14}$, the chances that the repetition will happen *later* are vanishingly small. (Not zero, but incredibly small indeed.) Note that this sadly does *not* prove that the repetition does *not* happen, so with all the discussion above, all we can tell your $8$yr old is that, *most likely*, there will be no repetition of the form `3.NNM` in the digits of $\pi$.

---

A funny thing is that, for the number $e\approx 2.718281828459\ldots$ you can see sort-of repetition, not on the first decimal but on the second decimal. However, if we allowed repetitions after an *arbitrary* decimal, then the whole problem turns on its head and you are *bound* to find repetitions of any size, somewhere in $\pi$, or in $e$, as long as those are [normal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number). (Which has been conjectured but not proven, by the way!) Say, if you want the same repetition of $1828$ found in $e$ to be found in $\pi$, you would just search for the sequence "$18281828$" in the digits of $\pi$, and you should find one such sequence every $10^8$ digits or so. (If $\pi$ is indeed a normal number.)

Answer (score -3):

Let $X$ be the target Sequence with $N$ Digits.
Let $A$ , $B$ , $C$ be arbitrary Sequences of non-Zero length.

Due to normality of transcendental number $\pi$ & taking the Digits to be some random Sequence **( assumption ! )** , these have a "guarantee" , in terms of Probability :
$3.AXBXC$ ( Due to having Infinite Cases varying over $A$ & $B$ )
$3.XAXB$ ( Due to having Infinite Cases varying over $A$ )

Whether that  **assumption** is true or not , this has no "guarantee" with $\pi$ :
$3.XXA$ (Due to no choice when $X$ is selected)
When some $N$ Digit $X$ will not work , we might take the next Digit to make new $N+1$ Digit $X$ : Probability will then reduce by $10^2$.
Overall Probability is $P=100^{-1}+100^{-2}+100^{-3}+... = 1/99$

We might have that "guarantee" when we consider $\pi$ & $e$ & all transcendental numbers together , where we have the stronger "guarantee" that it always **Deterministically Exists** without Probability.
Eg these will work :
$0.123456123456 + \pi \times 10^{-13}$
$0.123456789123456789 + e \times 10^{-19}$

There are numbers where it **Deterministically will not Exist** Eg :
$0.1020020002000020000020000002....$ where the $0$ Sequences will have lengths $1,2,3,4,5,6....$ terminating with $2$ & the Initial $1$ never reoccurs.

Comment: The normality of $\pi$ is not known.

Comment: *Due to normality of transcendental number* $\pi$ --- Not only is $\pi$ not known to be normal, it is not even known whether $\pi$ contains every finite digit string. Also, regarding the properties "transcendental" and "normal" (or even the property of having every finite digit string), a number can be transcendental without having this property (indeed, a number whose decimal expansion contains only $0$'s and $1$'s can be transcendental) and it is not yet known whether a normal number can be non-transcendental (i.e. normal and algebraic might be possible for all we know now).

Comment: My answer (in the negative) is not based on normality. I am only claiming that even with **assuming** normality , @GeoffreyTrang , that OP Pattern is unlikely while other Patterns might be likely.

Comment: Indeed , I have given example transcendental number with Digits $0,1,2$ , where OP Pattern never occurs & that is not even normal. I am **not claiming** that by assuming normality , Op Pattern will occur , @DaveL.Renfro , I am **claiming** that even normality is not enough to guarantee that OP Pattern will occur ! Is there something wrong in my claim ?

Comment: *I am claiming that even normality is not enough* --- It's not clear to me what you are arguing for. It sounds like you're saying normal numbers don't have to contain every finite digit string, but this is not true (in a strong way) -- see the paragraph beginning with "Among other things, this implies" in [this 18 September 2009 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/V0VsQhXYeWg/m/FZyc4mJRzO4J) (which incidentally is given in the MSE answer I previously cited here). (FYI, I have to leave for several hours now.)

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Even a normal number need not have the property that there is a positive integer $n$ such that the first $n$ digits repeat immediately. Isn't the Champerowne constant $0.123456789101112\cdots$ a counterexample ?

Comment: I am claiming that normality may imply X repeating somewhere in the middle Eg 0.AXBXC , normality will not imply X repeating with Initial Part itself Eg 0.XAXB , @DaveL.Renfro , & it will not even imply X repeating Immediately with Initial Part itself Eg 0.XXA , the OP Pattern !

Comment: Exactly what I am saying "Even a normal number need not have the property" , @Peter , which is what I mean by 3.XXA having no guarantee , that **the Initial Part X in $\pi$ will not Immediately repeat** , though I cooked-up 2 artificial Examples where Initial Part will repeat !!

Comment: I just got back, but here only for a moment . . . I'm still confused, and part of this may be due to lack of quantifiers (e.g. for 'A', 'X', 'B', etc. how are they prefaced -- "for all", "there exists", and in what order), but I'll skip that for now. "normality will not imply X repeating with Initial Part itself Eg 0.XAXB" -- Whatever sequence of initial digits of a normal number you choose (e.g. first million digits, first trillion digits, etc.), this same sequence (meaning, of course, in the same order) will repeat infinitely often. **(continued)**

Comment: This is because **any** finite sequence of digits (however you choose it) will appear infinitely often in any normal number. "& it will not even imply X repeating Immediately with Initial Part itself Eg 0.XXA" -- This seems to be misstated. You say "not even imply", which means what follows should be a weaker condition (since not implying a stronger condition is logically automatic, so one would not say "not *even*" imply"), but 'X' repeating right after 'X' is a stronger condition than 'X' repeating *somewhere* after 'X'. Maybe you meant something like "& thus certainly does not have to ..."?

Comment: (A) In first 2 lines I mentioned what X , A , B , C are. Eg , in P=0.771239812306... , target Sequence X=123 , fillers are A=77 , B=98 , C=06... , hence P=0.AXBXC : I claim this is Possible in $\pi$ , because we have infinite choices over A,B,C. (B) I claim ( In my Answer , though by over-sight , I made a mistake in my Earlier Comment , which should be ignored ) P=0.XAXB is also Possible , because we still have infinite choice over A. [[Cont]]

Comment: [[Cont]] (C) I claim P=0.XXA is not Possible because we have no choice , unlike the earlier  2 Cases. (D) Yes , your rewording with "Certainly" is Correct & what I meant , @DaveL.Renfro , I should have written it like this ".... & even more , it will not imply ...." , though that whole comment is invalid because I messed up 0.XAXB. In my Answer I mention that it is Possible !